# a floating action button above popup window

Tags: android, android-layout

Basically I am developping a android UI which contains a floating action button as well as a popup Window. I have set up two differents layout separately, one is activiy_main and another is popup. My goal is to make UI which is quite similar to that of google map.

https://www.google.com/url?sa=i&source=images&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwjXoo2GvP_hAhVrAGMBHRGXCuYQjRx6BAgBEAU&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.androidauthority.com%2Fgoogle-maps-multi-stop-directions-700971%2F&psig=AOvVaw3dtFX_biqy1dEV9tUjVGlh&ust=1556976616072449
Just like in this picture, there is a floating action button GPS(the white round one which is beyond the popup window.)

I want to make the button be at the bottom of the mapview when the popup window is not displayed(That's why i have left the main_activity in coordinatorlayout) and when it is poped up, the button should go up with the window which makes it always beyond it. Normally I think i can make this by organising them in one relative layout. However, I want to separete two layouts.

Is it a way to position a view in one layout relative above another view in another layout?

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/main_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">


        <AutoCompleteTextView
            android:id="@+id/search_view"
            android:layout_width="292dp"
            android:layout_height="43dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/ButtonEnvoyer"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/ButtonEnvoyer"
            android:layout_width="54dp"
            android:layout_height="46dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
            android:src="@drawable/places_ic_search"
            android:text="Recherche"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/search_view"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <org.osmdroid.views.MapView
            android:id="@+id/map"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/ButtonEnvoyer"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" />


    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>


        <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|right"
        android:layout_margin="16dp"
        android:src="@drawable/cursor"
        android:tint="@android:color/black"
        app:backgroundTint="@android:color/holo_blue_dark"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|right|end" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

popup.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="154dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/position"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="154dp"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
            android:background="@android:color/white"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:text="1333"
            android:textSize="18sp" />


    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

and popup window:

```
 public void pop(String pos){

        popupView = View.inflate(this, R.layout.popup, null);
        popupWindow = new PopupWindow(popupView, WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        TextView tv = popupView.findViewById(R.id.position);
        tv.setText(pos);
        popupWindow.setBackgroundDrawable(new BitmapDrawable());
        popupWindow.setFocusable(true);

        popupWindow.setOutsideTouchable(true);

        animation = new TranslateAnimation(Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT, 0, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT, 0,
                Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT, 1, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT, 0);
        animation.setInterpolator(new AccelerateInterpolator());
        animation.setDuration(200);

        popupWindow.showAtLocation(popupView, Gravity.BOTTOM, 10, 10);
        popupView.startAnimation(animation);

    }
```

Comment: How do you display the popup windows?

Comment: @BagolySz.     Thank you for reminding. I have edited and added my code of popup window

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could extend your `pop(String pos)` method with something similar as described below to animate the Floating Action Button:

First, should measure the size of the popup window, in order to calculate how much the button should be translated (note that the bottom padding of the FAB is substracted, in order to keep the same padding between popup window and FAB):

```
popupView.measure(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
int fabTranslationY = popupView.getMeasuredHeight() - fab.getPaddingBottom();
```

Next, set a dismiss listener on the popup window, so that the FAB goes back to it's initial position after the window is dismissed:

```
popupWindow.setOnDismissListener(new PopupWindow.OnDismissListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDismiss() {
            ObjectAnimator fabAnimator = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(fab, "translationY", 0);
            fabAnimator.setDuration(200);
            fabAnimator.setInterpolator(new AccelerateInterpolator());
            fabAnimator.start();
        }
    });
```

Finally, construct and start the translate animation of the FAB:

```
ObjectAnimator fabAnimator = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(fab, "translationY", -fabTranslationY);
fabAnimator.setDuration(200);
fabAnimator.setInterpolator(new AccelerateInterpolator());
fabAnimator.start();
```

Note: `fab = findViewById(R.id.fab);`

Don't forget to read about ObjectAnimator [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/animation/ObjectAnimator).

Comment: Thank you a lot although I have worked it out for with a workaround using Bottomsheet and anchor.